# Maple strange results while solving for complex equation

Tags: maple

I'm trying to make Maple solve a complex equation, but it produces an incorrect result.

The following images tells it all :
[image]

[image]
At (3) I would expect to get something close to 1 (as (2) shows), yet it gives me something that doesn't make any sense. Is it that the || (to express the complex number modulus) operator has another significance in the solve() function?

Comment: I kind of used with(RealDomain);, worked pretty great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restrict the values of `L` in the `solve` command with the `assuming` command.

Example 1:

```
G:= (w,L) -> (50+I*L*2*Pi*w)/(150+I*L*2*Pi*w);
result := evalf(5*abs(G(10,1)));

solve({5*abs(G(10,L)) = result},L) assuming L::real;
```

> ```
> {L = 1.000000000}, {L = -1.000000000}
> ```

Example 2:

```
G:=(f,L) -> (256.4+I*2*Pi*L*f)/(256.4+9845+I*2*Pi*L*f);
result := 5*abs(G(20000,0.03602197444));

solve({5*abs(G(20000,L)) = result},L) assuming L::real;
```

> ```
> {L = 0.03602197445}, {L = -0.03602197445}
> ```

Comment: Nice, I didn't know about this one. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The more appropriate function here is `fsolve`.

Example 1

```
restart:
G:=(w,L)->(5+I*L*2*Pi*w)/(150+I*L*2*Pi*w);
evalf(5*abs(G(10,1)));
fsolve(5*abs(G(10,L))=%,L=0..10)
```

Example 2

As above, you need to specify the interval `L=0..1` where the solution might be.

```
G:=(f,L)->(256.4+I*L*2*Pi*f)/(256.4+9845+I*L*2*Pi*f);
evalf(5*abs(G(20000,0.03602197444)));
fsolve(5*abs(G(20000,L))=%,L=0..1);
```

If you are facing difficulties to specify the interval then you should plot it first, it will give you an idea about it?

```
plot(5*abs(G(20000,L)),L=0..1)
```

Comment: Hi, I tried using fsolve() for another case and ended up wasting 30 mins just to finally understand Maple is giving me gibberish again. 2nd image shows it (edited question). I'm not sure at this point I can trust those results anymore anyways... (I was solving physical equations and getting an imaginary number meant something was wrong, when in fact nothing but the solver was wrong...) I would kind of need to tell maple I want pure real results only.